# Ng-Style conditional variable change not getting showing in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have my ng-style with conditional parameters, and it executes the conditional changes when the page is loaded.

But when I make some change in the conditional operator at runtime, in the controller side, the conditional parameter is not reflected in the html side.

I tried using `$scope.$apply()` and `$scope.reload()` but it doesn't give the required results.

```
<div ng-style="({{firstClick}})? 
     {'background-color':'blue'} :
     {'background-color':'red'}">
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdmqxr5y/38/)

Comment: `ng-style="(firstClick)? {'background-color':'blue'} :{'background-color':'red'}"` try this. Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bdmqxr5y/40/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<div ng-style = "firstClick == true ?
     {'background-color':'blue'}: 
     {'background-color':'red'}">
```

instead

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdmqxr5y/39/)

Answer (score 0):

change code to:

```
<div ng-style="'background-color':(firstClick?'blue':'red')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div ng-controller="myController"
     ng-style="firstClick === true? 
     {'background-color':'blue'} :
     {'background-color':'red'}">
```

It's working.